# Zero Knowledge range proof

Tags: cryptanalysis, protocol-design, homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs

I like the idea of a Zero Knowledge range proof. But I read that, to prove my age in a range, a commitment is required by a trusted party (TP) stating my age. How does that work? is the commitment a certificate from the TP?

Also, if I need a user “A” to prove to the verifier his current location (longitude, latitude) in a range without stating the exact location, can the zero knowledge range proof be helpful in that problem? Who should commit to that secret (in This case, user “A”'s current location) so it should be accurate? Can the TP be a trusted timestamped service or Google?

Comment: I can see that English is not your first language. But in that case, please try and keep to commonly accepted standards when it comes to white space, question marks and such. And please "prof" read your question before posting it, errors in the title really stand out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a commitment. The commitment comes from anyone who is trusted by the verifier to commit to genuine data. So to prove age, the date of birth, say seconds from epoch could come from a government issued ID. In case of lat-long, a location provider trusted by the verifier should be used so if verifier trusts Google.

There is vast literature and implementations and they provide varying guarantees like if you provide a proof to the same verifier twice but use the same commitment, the verifier will know that he has interacted with you before or not. Depends if you care about this or not. Regarding how they work, there are several techniques, a recent and popular is [Bulletproofs](https://crypto.stanford.edu/bulletproofs/). Another is this [paper](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/128718/files/CCS08.pdf).

Comment: Can the verifier be the Etherum blockchain? And the prover proves a specific statement that is on the blockchain ( his location in a particular area ) ??

Comment: For the ones i mentioned in the answer, yes, the verifier can be on Ethereum  (a smart contract). Have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/ing-bank/zkproofs). Yes, the commitment to the location can be on chain.

Comment: Thanks. I read the paper. It seems there are a lot of exchanged messages between the prover and verifier (Blockchain). Is that okay since the gas consumption would be very high??

Comment: according to the paper , the commitment is done by the prover on a number that is in the group. How the commitment can be provided such that it can be verified by the the verifier that a third party verified it? I think the commitment is only known for the prover.

Comment: The paper shows the interactive version of the proof which can be turned to a non-interactive one by using Fiat Shamir so you can let go of the step where verifier sends a challenge. Secondly, the first step of verifer is publishing of signatures which needs to be done only once by the verifier per range. The verifier can publish his signatures on the range and every prover can read them. So there is only 1 message sent by the prover if the verifier has published signatures already

Comment: The commitment might come from a signature provided to the prover by some trusted third party, say the government. The commitment is known to both verifier and prover, the committed value is known only to prover.

Comment: Assume a verifier stated that he is at Location X, then he sends his current location to TTP ( say google) that verifies if the location is accurate or not? . My question is how the commitment of X value which as you said known only to verifier, can be verified that it is legitimate and its content is already verified by the TTP ??

Comment: I didn't say X is known only to verifier, i think you meant prover. I meant between prover and verifier, X is known to prover. Depending on the scenario X might or might not be (a commmitment to X will be) known to trusted party.

Comment: please check the modified version of the ZKSP that I have just posted. I asked at the end of my question how to use Fiat-Shamir to general the challenge (c) that in the protocol in paper. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66998/59976

Comment: Please, you mentioned in your answer to use Fiat Shamir to compute "c".  why the prover does not just send it directly to the etherum smart contract with the proof values. can you exemplify how Fiat Shamir can be used?

Comment: The prover does not sends the challenge as it is to the verifier (smart contract here) but it uses the challenge to compute the proof. Both the verifier and prover are able to compute the same challenge

Comment: but in the paper, The verifier should send a challenge to the prover. As u mentioned,  How can that challenge computed by the verifier and put on the smart contract so that it can be used later by the prover to calculate the challenge? I have just asked that question here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67036/how-to-compute-a-challenge-c-using-fiat-shamir

Comment: Here the smart contract is acting as a verifier since it is the smart contract which verifies the proof. The challenge is generated by smart contract during proof verification. I suggest you read some basics of zero knowledge protocols, maybe start with [Sigma protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_knowledge#Sigma_protocols).

Comment: To be on the same page, what I am thinking is allow a user say (verifier) to publish a set $∅$, signatures, and the statement to be proven by another user ( name him the prover) on a smart contract. Then, if the prover proves to the smart contract that he knows a value in the set without explicitly defining which value, he will get some deposits. So, in your answer about the ZKSP mentioned on the paper https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-89255-7_15, u said the challenge can be computed by Fiat-Shamir so the protocol becomes non-interactive. So, how to compute that challenge ?

Comment: The user, which you call the verifier is also the verifier. So in this case the "proof verifier" is composed of 2 components, the user verifier and the smart contract. In your example proof verification consists of generating some initial data (the user verifier does this) and running an algorithm on the proof (the smart contract does this). Answering your other question now

Comment: I want the smart contract to just verify the proof received by a prover. simply my goal is to run the ZKP in the paper you have sent to me on the blockchain. I tried to reach u on twitter. I can send you the protocol on email. and u just tell me if it is okay?

Comment: @Mohamed sent a DM on twitter.